# GitHub Client on OS X Commit Fail ("Failed to add file ...)

Tags: git, github, laravel, laravel-4, github-for-mac

I am trying to commit changes I have made to my code (as usual) from my GitHub client on my Mac OS X Mavericks machine.  I added a new package to my project (it's a Laravel project, and I added the package Rocketeer.  I also made a few config changes).

I am getting the error:

```
Failed to add file laravel-master/vendor/anahki
```

When I uncheck this file in the commit list, it then goes to another file showing this error.

```
Failed to add file laravel-master/vendor/illumin
```

Any idea what is going on?  I have never run into these issues.  Thank you.

EDIT:

I have narrowed this down to two files that are not being allowed to commit (this is for a Laravel project):

These are the errors I get when I try to commit these two folders/files:

```
Failed to add file laravel-master/vendor/illuminate/remote/Illuminate/Remote/ to index.

Failed to add file laravel-master/vendor/anahkiasen/rocketeer/ to index.
```

Comment: do you have permissions to those files ? what's the permission on them ?

Comment: I should have permissions to all files.  They're just packages that were added to the framework.

Answer (score 30):

In my case, there was already a .git directory from another imported third-party git repository. I had to removed it, anything worked well.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. There was an existing `.git` repository at the location i wanted to create the new one. I deleted it and created a new one. Now committing works as expected.

If you aren't sure if there might be an existing `.git` at the target location of your repository, do this (on a Unix machine):

```
$> cd <path>
$> ls -aef
```

This should show you the hidden files (like `.git`). Now you have two options: either delete the `.git` directory

```
$> sudo rm -R .git
```

or change the owner rights.

Answer (score 5):

This is a weird error.

It seems to be a permissions error as indicated by git (command line), but persists even if permissions are 777.

What worked for me was going into terminal, `cd`ing into the directory, and manually adding it to the index.

So you would do:

```
cd <WHEREVER-YOUR-PROJECT-IS>/laravel-master/
sudo git add vendor/illuminate/remote/Illuminate/Remote/
sudo git add vendor/anahkiasen/rocketeer/
```

And then try the GitHub utility again.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I think this is caused by removing a file/dir then adding a new file/dir with the same name. Manually running git add -A in the terminal also solved this issue for me. Unfortunate that the app doesn't handle this case.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This was annoying me for weeks! I had to keep going into terminal and adding each file and committing from the terminal which isnt as nice as using the app. 

I finally contacted GitHub support and they advised me that they were aware of the issue and are releasing a fix soon.

**Open up your terminal or shell and navigate to the repository and enter:**

```
git config --local core.safecrlf false
```

This will disable the `core.safeclrf` property for the repository which is causing the issue.

That should work :)

**Note:** I am using the Mac version of the GitHub app (A New Hope (180))

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same issue, and this is not working for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My silly way to resolve this is to copy every files I needed and deleted the folder, then created a new folder with the same name and copied them back. It actually worked for me. I'm new to github and don't know how to find out the previously existing git file (though I did know it was probably caused by conflict between old and new config files). It's better to learn how github works to use it as a tool better. But for now, if you want to have a quick solution, mine might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround is to make a commit without the files that are causing the problem. Check the bad files off the commit list, do a local commit but don't push to the server, i.e. the button with circling arrows must **not** be green. Then go to your IDE, copy the content of the classes/files somewhere, then delete the problematic file. Create a new file and paste. Restart the github app, then do a commit with these new ones and then you can push. Worked for me.

I'm using v.185 (Responder Train).

Comment: I have hundreds of files, though? That would mean scrolling through a list of thousands of files and finding hundreds to check away.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might be work adding in here...

When I tried to commit my changes, I still had Xcode open. As such, the Github utility has issues adding files due to some security thing. I closed Xcode, but the error persisted in the Github utility. I had to close, and reopen the Github utility before it would work.

Food for thought!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the problem by manually creating a new folder. For example, I want to move a folder named "echarts" into my github repo. I just created a folder with the name echarts, and then copy the files in echarts and paste to the folder. It involves no git script.

Answer (score 0):

There might be different causes for the problem. For me, the file permissions were changed.

Run the following commands on the terminal :

```
$ cd <path>
$ chmod u+rw file.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if you have Xcode installed.  There was a EULA agreement I needed to agree to before it would allow me to commit